# How can I send React post request with file data to an API?

Tags: reactjs, django

Here I want to register user with image so I want to pass both image and name in my formdata.
I am able to upload the file using some guideline (I am not good with react) but I am not able to pass the input name with my formdata. which procedure to follow?

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import { Table, Button, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const UPLOAD_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/vendor/register/";

function VendorRegistration() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("avatar", file);
    formData.append("name", name);
   
    const resp = await axios.post(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
      
    });
    console.log(resp.status)
  };

  

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h1>React File Upload</h1>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
      
      <button type="submit" disabled={!(file && name)}>
        Upload File
      </button>
      {resp.status == 200(
      <h1>ok</h1>
      )
}
    </form>

    
  );
  
}

export default VendorRegistration;
```

Comment: `input type="name"` is not a thing at all, for one. `type="text"` is, and then you'd just add your usual `onChange` handler and `value` prop to make it a controlled input, and send the value along in the formData.

Comment: You can see this similar implementation formdata with file post request https://github.com/maurya20/drf_react_blog/blob/master/frontend/src/components/Writeblog.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just want to bind the other input to state as per usual, and then add that value to the form data.

I added rudimentary validation that prevents clicking the submit button unless both fields are filled in, too.

**EDIT:** I also added status responses, as per comments.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const UPLOAD_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/vendor/register/";

function VendorRegistration() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const { userInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    setStatus(""); // Reset status
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("avatar", file);
    formData.append("name", name);
    const resp = await axios.post(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData, {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    });
    setStatus(resp.status === 200 ? "Thank you!" : "Error.");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h1>React File Upload</h1>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
      <button type="submit" disabled={!(file && name)}>
        Upload File
      </button>
      {status ? <h1>{status}</h1> : null}
    </form>
  );
}

export default VendorRegistration;
```

Comment: Hey this works perfectly. Thank you so much. Would you help me a little more. Like now if the request is success then send him a message or redirect him to another page how can I do this? if not success then I want to show the error message too

Comment: Instead of `return await ...`, you'd do `const resp = await ...` and look at the contents of `resp`.

Comment: I have updated my code. Can you see what I did wrong? I want to the h1 tag if the resp.status == 200

Comment: Well, what you did is... just not quite correct. See my edit; I added a status state there.